# Ocultar Subitems de um ListView?

Tags: delphi, listview

Existe alguma forma de ocultar subitems e os seus dados de um `listview`?

Tentei começar o código com algo assim:

```
for I := 0 to Form1.LV1.Items.Count-1 do
      begin
            if Form1.LV1.Items[I].SubItems[5] = 'OK' then
      begin
```

Mais não sei como continuar para EXIBIR somente os SUBITEMS com o TEXTO "OK" ...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, na verdade estou quebrando a cabeça aqui....não consegui bolar nada. Imagina o seguinte, eu tenho um LISTVIEW com 3 COLUNAS, nesse LISTVIEW insiro vários registros....quando o REGISTRO é CONCLUÍDO eu uso o BOTÃO para atualizar o mesmo e colocar um "OK" na frente. Preciso que eu tenha um outro BOTÃO, quando eu clique nele, ele "esconda" os REGISTROS sem o "OK" e mostre somente os com o "OK" deu pra entender?

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente não há como fazer isso, pelo menos não nativamente.

A ideia que tive para tentar contornar isso foi de guardar os dados em uma lista de strings(`StringList`) em uma variável global.

### Atualização

Faça o seguinte:

```
{ Declare na cláusula Uses as units StrUtils e Types }
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  StringList: TStringList;   // Variável global

{ 
   Procedimento responsável por carregar os itens salvos da StringList em um
   Listview declarado por você.
}
procedure ListViewLoadItems(Listview: TListView);
var
I, J: Integer;
Fields: TStringDynArray;  { Na seção Uses declare System.StrUtils e System.Types }
Item: TListItem;
begin
try
ListView.Clear;
for i := 0 to StringList.Count-1 do begin
    Fields := SplitString(StringList[i], #9);
    Item := Listview.Items.Add;
    Item.Caption := Fields[0];
    for j := 1 to high(Fields) do Item.SubItems.Add(Fields[j]);
end;
finally
    StringList.Free;
end;
end;

{
   Procedimento responsável por salvar os itens na StringList.
   NOTA: Só será salvo os itens em que o SubItem[4] não conter a sequência
   ""OK""

}
procedure ListViewSaveItems;

 procedure AddTextToLine(var Line: string; const Text: string);
 begin
    Line := Line + Text + #9;
 end;

 procedure MoveCompletedLineToList(const Strings: TStringList; var Line: string);
 begin
    Strings.Add(Copy(Line, 1, Length(Line)-1));
    Line := '';
 end;

Var
  Tempstr: string;
  I, J: Integer;

begin
StringList := TStringList.Create;
Tempstr := '';
try
for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count -1 do
if (ListView1.Items.Item[i] <> nil) and
   (not ListView1.Items.Item[i].SubItems[4].Equals('OK')) then begin
AddTextToLine(Tempstr, ListView1.Items[i].Caption);

for j := 0 to ListView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count -1 do begin
    AddTextToLine(Tempstr, ListView1.Items[i].SubItems[j]);
end;
MoveCompletedLineToList(StringList, Tempstr);
end;
except
// ....
end;
end;
```

Esse código foi adaptado para a sua situação a partir [dessa resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073748/1608936). Para utilizar basta colocar dois botões e chamar os procedimentos, veja um exemplo:

Salvar os itens:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnSaveitemsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListViewSaveItems; // Salvará os itens
end;
```

Carregar os itens salvos em um outro `Listview`:

```
procedure TForm1.BtnLoadItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if StringList = nil then exit; // Verifica se StringList é válido
ListViewLoadItems(ListView2);  // Carrega os itens salvos na *Listview2*
end;
```

Veja essa ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão `Save` os itens que não conterem no seu *SubItem **4*** a palavra **OK** serão salvos.

Agora ao clicar no botão `Load` será mostrado algo parecido com isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso deve funcionar para você.

Comment: eu essa opção SplitString não existe no delphi7, o que posso colocar no lugar ?

Answer (score 1):

Você por usar um `TClientDataSet` em memória.

Para esconder os registros que você deseja que não apareçam, basta você colocar um filtro no `ClientDataSet` e então na *listView* fazer `.invalidate`, e carregar na visualização somente os registros desejados através do `ClientDataSet`.

Nesta estratégia você não carrega todos os dados na `TListView`, todos os dados ficam carregados no CDs. Você transfere do CDs para a `ListView` somente aqueles que são para visualização naquele momento.

No lugar do CDs, você pode pensar em usar outros recursos, como por exemplo um `TList` de Objetos, através dele você também consegue fazer um *sort* se precisar e caminhar nos registros com eficiência de memória e velocidade. Mas te digo que o CDs é completo para você gerenciar os dados da forma que desejar.